# Count Up not stopping

Tags: javascript

Need that, the counter should  be start after button click, when start count up - start button must be inactive, after count up finish - button must be active and have someone function.

```
var refDate = new Date("2013 01 18 16:41");
var prepend = "This is a message ";
var append = new Date(refDate).toLocaleString();
var refValue = "1,100.00";

function insertCommas(nAmt) {
var currAmt = nAmt.toFixed(2);
while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(currAmt)) {
currAmt = currAmt.replace(/(\d+)(\d{3})/, "$1,$2");
}
return currAmt;
}

function dispCounter() {
var currDate = new Date();
var elapsedSeconds = Math.round((refDate - currDate) / 100);
var elapsedValue = elapsedSeconds / 100;
var nRef = refValue.replace(/\,/g, "");
var result = insertCommas(nRef - elapsedValue);
document.getElementById('upCount').innerHTML = prepend + " $" + result + " since " + append;
setTimeout("dispCounter()", 1500);
}

navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer" ? attachEvent('onload', dispCounter, false) : addEventListener('load', dispCounter, false);
```

Comment: Why would it ever stop? Every call to `dispCounter` *unconditionally* calls `dispCounter` again. Your `setTimeout` call should probably be in some sort of `if` statement.

Comment: Nitpick: This is a bad way to detect support. `navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer"`

Comment: I am a beginner, and I can not find a solution.

Comment: Under what condition(s) should the counting cease? User 'jbabey' has made a suggestion; do you understand that suggestion?

Comment: From button click start  "0.00" to  X date  "110.00"  = finish/button active